# How do I assign a random set word value to a variable in JavaScript? (Discord JS v12H)

Tags: javascript, random, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a guessing game with my Discord bot where when I type "!guessing game". It will react with three emojis: 1️⃣, 2️⃣, and 3️⃣. Then it randomly chooses one of those emojis and assigns it to the variable, "*answer*". And if I click the emoji that corresponds with the one that is set to the "*answer*" variable then it will say something like "Congratulations! You guessed the correct number!", and if not, it would say "Aww! Better luck next time!" or something.

This is my code:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === "!guessing game") {
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === msg.author.id;
        };
        msg.react('1️⃣');
        msg.react('2️⃣');
        msg.react('3️⃣');
        msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();
                var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
                if (num === "1") {
                    var answer = "1️⃣"
                }
                else {
                    if (num === "2") {
                        var answer = "2️⃣"
                    }
                    else {
                        if (num === "3") {
                            var answer = "3️⃣"
                        }
                        else {
                           console.log("Random num failed")
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === answer) {
                    msg.reply('You did it!');
                }
                else {
                    msg.reply('Better luck next time!');
                }
            })
```

Naturally, this is what my console said: "Random num failed"
I have a feeling that it would be a lot more efficient to choose a random emoji rather a random number and then converting it to an emoji.

How can I fix this? Could it be made case insensitive?

Comment: The last part of the code seems to be missing. There are 13 `{`s and 11 `}`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `==` instead of `===` in your `if (num === "1")` statements or remove double quotes around the number—`if (num === 1)`.

That's because the `===` operator is more strict; it stands for comparing value and type of the value. The `Math.random()` function returns the value of the `number` type, so you are comparing `number` to `string`:

```
console.log(3 == "3"); // Will return true
console.log(3 === "3"); // Will return false
```

More information is on *[Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)*.

Comment: ahh. Thanks. I'll keep that in mind when im working with variables.

Comment: Do you know what to do about the case insensitivity though? when i say !Guessing game, it doesn't work so i need to make it so it converts it all to lower case.

Comment: @Datonebassdude use : `YourVariable.toLowerCase();` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also have made your code a lot shorter using:

```js
const numbers = ['1️⃣','2️⃣','3️⃣'];
let randNum = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
// Output: '1️⃣' or '2️⃣' or '3️⃣' :)
```

Comment: @Datonebassdude No problem :) Please consider upvoting answers that where helpful to you using the arrows next to them :)